# ORACLE UPDATE CORRELATED QUERY

Tags: oracle

I have an update query as below which is using correlated method. This is taking too long to run.
Is there a better way to rewrite this. Appreciate your help in advance.

```
UPDATE DAC A
   SET (acc_obj_header,
        acc_sub_header,
        acc_desc_header
   ) = (SELECT B.acc_obj,
               B.acc_sub,
               B.acc_desc
          FROM DAC B
         WHERE B.country_code = A.country_code
           AND B.comp_no = A.comp_no
           AND B.bu_no = A.bu_no
           AND B.acc_level_of_detail < A.acc_level_of_detail
           AND (B.acc_obj || B.acc_sub) = (SELECT MAX(C.acc_obj || C.acc_sub)
                                             FROM DAC C
                                            WHERE C.country_code = A.country_code
                                              AND C.comp_no = A.comp_no
                                              AND C.bu_no         =A.bu_no
                                              AND (C.acc_obj || C.acc_sub) <= (A.acc_obj || A.acc_sub)
                                              AND C.acc_level_of_detail < A.acc_level_of_detail
                                          )
           AND rownum < 2
       )
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this update?

Comment: Sorry It is written by developer who left the office recently.I am trying to tweak this without any idea. I have to come up with sample data and try

Answer (score 1):

When I faced with long-working updates like it I rewrote it to MERGE statement. So if the query works fast by itself just rewrite to merge else consider about rewriting the query.

I hope you have an FBI (function-based index) on (b.acc_obj || b.acc_sub) - it could improve the performance slightly.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As of now there are no FBIs but i would try doing that and see. I have read that correlated subquery can only go one level deep, but I believe my query has two level depth of correlation or I may be wrong ??

Comment: I think your query is fine but there is a possible reason of performance issue - you invoke MAX very often. Try to mess about analytical MAX function in order to get rid of the second subquery.